# What is the reaction between nitric acid and fluorine?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

Nitric acid, $\ce{HNO3}$, is a strong oxidising agent as well as fluorine, $\ce{F2}$. What will be the reaction when pure $\ce{F2}$ gas is bubbled through 100% pure $\ce{HNO3}$. While searching, many products are suggested including $\ce{HF}$, $\ce{O2}$, $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{NO}$, $\ce{NO2}$, $\ce{NF3}$, $\ce{NO2FO}$, etc.. What is correct?

Answer (score 7):

It was first discovered by Cady that when fluorine is bubbled through $\pu{3 N}$ nitric acid, then a remarkable compound, fluorine nitrate ($\ce{FNO3}$) is formed. It boils at $\pu{-42 ^\circ C}$ and is a very strong oxidizing agent and is capable of liberating iodine from iodides and in gaseous states, it explodes around $\pu{200-300 ^\circ C}$.

**References**

1. The reaction of Fluorine with Nitric acid and with solid Potassium Nitrate to form NO3F by Don M. Yost and Alan Beerbower,  *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* April **1935**, 57(4) 782. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01307a520
2. Prof. Dr. Otto Ruff, Dr. Walter Kwasnikie,  Die Fluorierung der Salpetersäure. Das Nitroxyfluorid – NO3F, April **1935**, DOI: https://doi.org/10.1002/ange.19350481604 [German paper]